# JS access every single element in forloop

Tags: javascript, django, for-loop

I want a button in for loop can run the same function independently for click the hidden  while click the , but no response after clicked.

html for-loop:

```
         {% for order_item in orders %}
          <a class="btn btn-warning" >Upload File</a>
          <input type="file" id="img-file{{ forloop.counter }}" hidden="hidden"/>
          <button type="button" onclick="function upload_img({{ forloop.counter }}){}">Upload</button>
        {% endfor %}
```

js:

```
<script>
function upload_img(x) {
    const realFileBtn = document.getElementById('img-file'+x);

    realFileBtn.click()

}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: `function` should not be in the onclick.... You are defining a function on every onclick, not calling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call function inside `onclick` not define.

```
onclick="upload_img({{ forloop.counter }})"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function in button tag and it's called anywhere which is wrong, you have to call it somewhere.

Create the function named `upload_img` and call it inside `onclick` like this

`onclick="upload_img({{ forloop.counter }})"`